# SQL Group By Having

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to List all orders from the month and year of October 2017 and their totals in date order
chronologically.

but it does not work. There's an error which occurs. Any insight on where i'm going wrong? Tried Group by and Group by having.

Here is what I have:

```
      SELECT *
      FROM [db.name]
      WHERE record_date.YEAR =2017, record_date.MONTH =October 
      GROUP BY record_date.YEAR, record_date.MONTH
      ORDER BY ASC;
```

Comment: For one: `record_date.MONTH =  'October'`. More importantly your select should just be `SELECT Order_ID, Sum(Order_price)` or what-have-you. If you share sample data from this table and desired results we can help out more.

Comment: Multiple conditions within a where clause must be added using AND instead of comma. This is very likely not the only issue. I think you should provide sample data and the desired result, please.

Comment: October is read as an identifier here, i.e. a column name. Use a literal instead, like `'October'` (or perhaps 10.)

Comment: 1) `record_date.YEAR =2017, record_date.MONTH =October` should be `record_date.YEAR =2017 AND record_date.MONTH ='October'`  2) `ORDER BY ASC` shoudl be `ORDER BY ______ ASC` where the _____ is the date field you want to order by..  3) [db.name] can we assume this is `record_date` otherwise your aliased columns are wrong.

Comment: If you're only selecting records from one month, there's no point in grouping by the month.